# Turning off notifications when creating a node (even though autosubscribe is set)

Tags: php, drupal

I created a module in drupal that makes books where every page is a separate node.  I can create books using an importer, but when I do this, I am sent a notifcation when each node is created if I have autosubscribe on.  It is really bad when importing a 500 page book ;)

Is there a way to create nodes like this without being notified every time a page is created? I feel like their is a simple answer and I just don't know enough about drupal

Comment: Can you give a bit more details - which Drupal version, what 'autosubscribe' functionality and the import node creation code? (If the 'autosubscribe' setting is stored as a Drupal Variable, you might be able to temporarily override it during node import by manipulating it in the ´global $conf´ array.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: http://drupal.org/project/disable_messages